# RecyclerView itemView image drawable being changed when scrolling back to top

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, backendless

I have a problem with my recyclerview. When I scroll down everything is ok but when I scroll back to top the drawable that I set to images is being changed.
Here's my Adapter code:

```
    @Override
    public FeedsHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.feed_item, parent, false);

        final FeedsHolder holder = new FeedsHolder(view);

        //Query

        QueryOptions options = new QueryOptions();

        options.setRelated(Arrays.asList("usersThatLike"));

        BackendlessDataQuery query = new BackendlessDataQuery();

        query.setQueryOptions(options);

        Backendless.Data.of(Feeds.class).find(query, new AsyncCallback<BackendlessCollection<Feeds>>() {

            @Override

            public void handleResponse(BackendlessCollection<Feeds> response) {
                String userId = Backendless.UserService.CurrentUser().getObjectId();
                for (Feeds feed : response.getData()) {
                    feed = list.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());

                    List<BackendlessUser> likedUsers = feed.getUsersThatLike();
                    for (BackendlessUser user : likedUsers)
                        if (user.getObjectId().equals(userId)) {
    //** GOOGLE MATERIAL ICON WITH FILLED HEART
                            setBackground(holder.like, ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_favorite_black_24dp));
                        } else if (!user.getObjectId().equals(userId)) {
    //** GOOGLE MATERIAL ICON WITH EMPTY HEART
                            setBackground(holder.like, ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_black_24dp));
                        }
                }

            }

            @Override

            public void handleFault(BackendlessFault backendlessFault) {

            }

        });
        return holder;
    }
```

And than I set the default image of the holder.like imageview in onBindViewHolder:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final FeedsHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.like.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_black_24dp));
    }
```

And I think this is the problem...

But I don't know how to solve this because without this line of code my other rows of recyclerview will have different images: some will have filled heart and some will have empty.

So please help me find a solution.

**EDIT:** Posting my Adapter code

```
    public class FeedAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FeedAdapter.FeedsHolder> {

    private List<Feeds> list;
    private Context context;
    private static List<Long> selectedIds;
    List<BackendlessUser> backendlessUserList;
    private List<Comments> cake = new ArrayList<>();
    private static String TAG = "MainActivity";

    public FeedAdapter(Context context, List<Feeds> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;

    }

    @Override
    public FeedsHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.feed_item, parent, false);

        final FeedsHolder holder = new FeedsHolder(view);

        //Query

        QueryOptions options = new QueryOptions();

        options.setRelated(Arrays.asList("usersThatLike"));

        BackendlessDataQuery query = new BackendlessDataQuery();

        query.setQueryOptions(options);

        Backendless.Data.of(Feeds.class).find(query, new AsyncCallback<BackendlessCollection<Feeds>>() {

            @Override

            public void handleResponse(BackendlessCollection<Feeds> response) {
                myFeeds = response;
                String userId = Backendless.UserService.CurrentUser().getObjectId();
                for (Feeds feed : response.getData()) {
                    feed = list.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());

                    List<BackendlessUser> likedUsers = feed.getUsersThatLike();
                    backendlessUserList = likedUsers;
                    for (BackendlessUser user : likedUsers)
                        if (user.getObjectId().equals(userId)) {
                            setBackground(holder.like, ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_favorite_black_24dp));
                        } else if (!user.getObjectId().equals(userId)) {
                            setBackground(holder.like, ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_black_24dp));
                        }
                }

            }

            @Override

            public void handleFault(BackendlessFault backendlessFault) {

            }

        });
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final FeedsHolder holder, final int position) {
        //Starting Feeds
        final Feeds feeds = list.get(position);

        holder.like.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_black_24dp));

        //Name
        holder.name.setText(feeds.getOwner());

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public class FeedsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        //Setup Views
        CardView card;
        TextView name;

        public FeedsHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            //Assign views by ID
            card = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.commenter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't be querying the backend inside onCreateViewHolder, instead to that outside and pass the response to the adapter via constructor or setter, again, check my example, is pretty strightforward

Comment: I wanted to query backendless data in onCreateViewholder so that it won't update every time the list is scrolled up/down (I know how RecyclerView works... Just tried to have some luck here). If I put the query code in onBindViewHolder than the image drawable is being empty heart for all the rows and it get updated after 3/4 seconds when you keep viewing the row (takes time to query data). So I wanted to make it solid so it won't get updated every time one scroll up/down...

Comment: "I wanted to query backendless data in onCreateViewholder so that it won't update every time the list is scrolled up/down".. I think you're wrong, you do not have to call the backend inside onCreateViewholder. Call it outside, and store the response in a variable inside the adapter (breweries in my example). Then, refresh the views using onBindViewHolder.

Comment: Sorry but I'm a bit newbie in that. Can you please try to edit my code? I will be grateful to you! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the state of the cell (for example what image needs to be shown) somewhere. One option is to have a list with the same size of your data source, and store a value indicating if the element in that position will have a empty heart, a full heart, or nothing, and finally check for that value in `onBindViewHolder`, and update the view properly.

EDIT: here is an example:

```
public class BreweryRecyclerViewAdapter
       extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BreweryRecyclerViewAdapter.BreweryRecyclerViewViewHolder>
       implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static List<Long> selectedIds;

    private Context context;
    private List<Brewery> breweries;
    private View.OnClickListener clickListener;

    public BreweryRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context) {
        clearBreweries();
        this.context = context;
    }

    public BreweryRecyclerViewAdapter(List<Brewery> breweries) {
        setBreweries(breweries);
    }

    public List<Brewery> getBreweries() {
        return breweries;
    }

    public void setBreweries(List<Brewery> breweries) {
        this.breweries = breweries;
        selectedIds = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void setClickListener(View.OnClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
    }

    public void clearBreweries() {
        this.breweries = Collections.emptyList();
        selectedIds = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public BreweryRecyclerViewViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_brewery, parent, false);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        return new BreweryRecyclerViewViewHolder(context, itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(BreweryRecyclerViewViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Brewery brewery = breweries.get(position);
        if (selectedIds.contains(brewery.getId())) {
            holder.openSecondaryLayoutVisibility();
        } else {
            holder.closeSecondaryLayoutVisibility();
        }
        holder.update(brewery);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return breweries.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (clickListener != null) {
            clickListener.onClick(view);
        }
    }

    public static class BreweryRecyclerViewViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        @BindView(R.id.brewery_name)
        TextView breweryName;

        @BindView(R.id.brewery_distance)
        TextView breweryDistance;

        @BindView(R.id.brewery_duration)
        TextView breweryDuration;

        @BindView(R.id.brewery_time)
        TextView breweryTime;

        @BindView(R.id.brewery_is_happy_hour)
        ImageView breweryIsHappyHour;

        @BindView(R.id.secondary)
        RelativeLayout secondaryLayout;

        @BindView(R.id.brewery_description)
        TextView breweryDescription;

        private Context context;
        private Brewery brewery;

        public BreweryRecyclerViewViewHolder(Context context, View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
            this.context = context;
        }

        public Brewery getBrewery() {
            return brewery;
        }

        public void toggleSecondaryLayoutVisibility(Long id) {
            if (secondaryLayout.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
                openSecondaryLayoutVisibility();
                selectedIds.add(id);
            } else {
                closeSecondaryLayoutVisibility();
                selectedIds.remove(id);
            }
        }

        public void openSecondaryLayoutVisibility() {
            secondaryLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        public void closeSecondaryLayoutVisibility() {
            secondaryLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @OnClick(R.id.view_route_button)
        public void viewRouteButtonClicked(Button button) {
            String latitude = brewery.getLocation().getLatitude().toString();
            String longitude = brewery.getLocation().getLongitude().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(
                    String.format("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=%s,%s", latitude, longitude)));
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }

        public void update(Brewery brewery) {
            breweryName.setText(brewery.getName());
            if (brewery.getDistanceHumanReadable() == null) {
                breweryDistance.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                breweryDistance.setText(String.format("%s | ", brewery.getDistanceHumanReadable()));
                breweryDistance.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            if (brewery.getDurationHumanReadable() == null) {
                breweryDuration.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                breweryDuration.setText(String.format("%s | ", brewery.getDurationHumanReadable()));
                breweryDuration.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            breweryTime.setText(String.format("%shs a %shs", brewery.getOpen(), brewery.getClose()));
            breweryIsHappyHour.setVisibility(brewery.isHappyHour() ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            breweryDescription.setText(brewery.getDescription());

            this.brewery = brewery;
        }

    }

}
```

put attention on `onBindViewHolder` and in `toggleSecondaryLayoutVisibility`, to see the use of `selectedIds` to keep the cell state.

Comment: Can you please provide an example code for keeping the cell's state?

Comment: Thanks for your example code. What's secondaryLayout in your example? Seems hard to understand as there are so many functions that I don't have in my adapter. Can you please provide your email so I can send you my full code so you can better understand it?

Comment: secondaryLayout is something that I show/hide when the user clicks in the cell (I keep this information so when scrolling back, the cell is still "selected")